# Monitor flickers in native resolution

Tags: drivers, resolution, nvidia-geforce

With my new Samsung Syncmaster BX2450 I have the following problem:

In Windows XP (SP2), all resolutions above 1440x900 have either strange pixel errors or an extreme flickering. It seems, that the effect worsens for higher resolutions.
In special, I would like to run the monitor with its native resolution (1920x1080), however I can't watch longer than 5 seconds on the monitor because of the flickering...

My Graphics Card is a Geforce FX 5200 with the most up-to-date driver (according to Nvidia.com: Forceware 175.19) and I'm having the monitor connected to its DVI-output.

The strange thing is, under Ubuntu 10.04, all resolutions work just perfect, so the display must be alright.

edit: seems to be a driver problem... if I use the proprietary NVIDIA drivers in Ubuntu, I have the same problem as in Windows.

**I would like to reformulate my question:**

Is there a modified/alternative Geforce FX 5200 driver (as there is in Ubuntu) for Windows that allows me to use 1920x1020 without problems ? I already tried the [omega drivers](http://www.omegadrivers.net/index.php?option=com_phocadownload&view=category&id=7&Itemid=90): unfortunately, it still looks poor on the native resolution.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Samsung](http://www.samsung.com/hk_en/consumer/computer-peripherals/monitors/consumer/LS24B5HVFH/XK/index.idx?pagetype=prd_detail&subsubtype=50-series), the BX2450 has the native resolution of 1920x1080.

With any higher resolution, what you are seeing is only interpolation. So evidently, the Linux driver does it better.

I would suggest staying at 1920x1080. As regarding flickering, you might have a look at the refresh rate.

Comment: My problem is that every resolution ABOVE 1440x900 (which of course includes the native resolution 1920x1020, which is also the maximal resolution i tried) shows flickering. I didn't (and won't) try any resolution above the native resolution.

Comment: Above or below the native resolution means interpolation. What is the refresh rate?

Comment: The refresh rate is 60Hz, as recommended (I can't change it anyway).

Comment: You have done all that is in your power to do, and the monitor is probably defective in a way that only shows in Windows. You may try to use the warranty, or if in Windows 7 degrade the display (turn off Aero).

Comment: The problem seems to be that the FX 5200 supports DVI-resolutions only up to 1600x1200 (which, after another driver update, I can confirm: up until 1600x1200 the picture is kind of alright, but the native solution is still messed up). source: http://www.nvidia.com/page/pg_20040109440047.html

Comment: You didn't mention DVI before. Why do you attempting to display beyond the manufacturer's specs? For example, [here](http://www.computer-juice.com/forums/f42/samsung-226bw-monitor-screen-flicker-12710/) the solution was to use an hdmi-to-dvi connector. In other posts they called Samsung and got a replacement monitor.

Answer (score 0):

You could go to "Change Resolution" from the Nvidia control panel.

Comment: How does it answer the question?